# Django filter in ModelForm with specific models

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Report(models.Model):  
    # ....
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Item(models.Model):
    box = models.ForeignKey(BoxInTransport)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)


class BoxInTransport(models.Model):
    transport = models.ForeignKey(Transport)
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box)
```

This is - in short - the structure of models.

And I have a view which lets me create new report:

```
class ReportCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Report
    form_class = ReportForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # updating to get argument from url
        kwargs = super(DifferenceCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
        return kwargs
```

and the form:

```
class ReportForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = [
            'product'
        ]

    def __init__(self, box_nr=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['product'].queryset = ???
```

How can I get only these products which belong to a specific box? To be more clear:

Only products which:

```
Item.objects.filter(box__box__box_code=box_nr)
```

Now I get all Items which I need, but I need to pass self.fields['products']  to only product form with this new Items queryset.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

I've tried something like this:

```
 def __init__(self, box_nr=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(
        box__box__box_code=boxno
    )
    none_queryset = Product.objects.none()
    list_or_products = [p.product for p in queryset]
    product_queryset = list(chain(none_queryset, list_or_products))
    self.fields['product'].queryset = product_queryset
```

But, first - it looks little ugly :), second - it doesn't work:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: Your table structure doesn't make much sense. Why is it that `Item` has a ForeignKey to `BoxInTransit` **and** `BoxInTransit` has a foreignkey to `Item`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` could look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, box_nr=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    qs = Product.objects.filter(item__box__box__box_code=box_nr)
    self.fields['product'].queryset = qs
```

Basically, you need a reverse lookup on `Product` to `Item`. You can read the [relevant documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Note that: `item__box__box__box_code=box_nr` is based on my understanding of your models. `item__box` does the reverse lookup. Rest might need some tweaking based on your model definitions.

Comment: I added releated_name to product filed in Item model. And then: qs = Product.objects.filter(item__box__box__box_code=box_nr). But this gave me an error: Related Field got invalid lookup: box

Comment: Then use the related name you used in the reverse lookup.

Comment: I added related_name = 'item' :)

Comment: This is what do you mean?

Comment: sure, Your reverse relationship would have been `item` anyways.